# Function to turn local variable into class variable

Tags: android-studio

How to add these two functions to android studio, to turn a existing (not accessible) variable into a private/public? The screenshot is faked and not real, but it is the aim of my question.

**To turn a local variable into private/public I have to do the following steps:**
- Cut `[variable-class] [variable-name]` 
- Write `[private/public]`  
- Change cursor position to class-head
- Paste `[variable-class] [variable-name]` 
- Copy `[variable-name]` 
- Change cursor position to class-method 
- Paste `[variable-name]`

[image]

Answer (score 16):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> will extract your local variable into the class field.
To learn other available refactorings, you can read the [Intellij Idea Reference Card](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf).

Answer (score 5):

Thank you @Ofek! Your answer was okay but not perfect ;) So I'm going to add some details.

1. Change cursor position to variable
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
[image: img1]

3. To open extra settings press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> once again:
[image: img2]

4. If you have finished, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:
[image: img3]

**Additional:**

To change <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to a desired combination follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32117198/4406921).

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings->Editor->Key-Map, search for "field" and define a shortcut to Extract a Field.